# Catch an 'as' typecast exception in flutter

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

how can i catch an 'as' typecast exception in flutter. For example this causes an expection as the cast wasn't successful.

```
final success = mapJson['success'] as String;
```

In Swift we can use a `guard let` or an `if let` statement. Is there something similar for flutter/dart?

Comment: Do you want to show another value if the default value is null? If thats the case you can use something like this: `mapJson['success'] as String ?? " ";`

Comment: @P4yam This doesn't solve the OP's problem because there will still be an uncaught exception.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Yes thats actually why I posted this comment. I'm not an ios developer but as I know `if let` statement does something like `??` cast

Comment: @P4yam no, i want to return the function when the casting fails or throw an error that i can catch. But the users below posted it already. I hope there's a shorter version of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `try-catch` block to catch all exceptions in nearly any situation. You can read more about them [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_exceptions.htm) and from many other places online.

Example usage:

```
void main() {
  int x = 3;
  var posVar;

  try{
    posVar = x as String;
  }
  catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }
  print(posVar);
}
```

This print outs

```
TypeError: 3: type 'JSInt' is not a subtype of type 'String'
null
```

on DartPad and will be different in a real environment. The code in the `try` block throws an exception that is caught and can be handled in the `catch` block.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't there a much shorter solution?

Comment: AFAIK this is the *only* way of catching exceptions in dart.

Answer (score 6):

Extending the Answer of @Christopher you can even catch specific exceptions using the `on` block and execute exception specific code:

```
try {

// ...

 } on SomeException catch(e) {

//Handle exception of type SomeException
  print(e)

} catch(e) {

 //Handle all other exceptions
 print(e)

} finally {

  // code that should always execute; irrespective of the exception 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. Isn't there a much shorter solution?

Answer (score 2):

The Swift guard-let and if-let are used to avoid `null` values (`nil` in Swift) and either assign the non-null value to a variable, or execute the else branch (which must contain a control-flow operation in the `guard` case).

Dart has other patterns for doing the same thing, based on type promotion. Here I'd do:

```dart
final success = mapJson['success'];
if (success is String) {
 ... success has type `String` here!
}
```

With the (at time of writing yet upcoming) Null Safety feature's improved type promotion, you can even write:

```dart
final success = mapJson['success'];
if (success is! String) return; //  or throw or another control flow operation.
... success has type `String` here!
```

You *should not* make the code throw and then catch the *error* (it's not an `Exception`, it's an `Error`, and you should not catch and handle errors). The ["don't use try/catch for control flow"](https://wiki.c2.com/?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl) rule from other languages also applies to Dart.
Instead do a test before the cast, and most likely you won't need the cast because the type check promotes.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Null-aware operator to avoid unwanted Null and crash.
this is short an alternative to try catch (which is more powerful).

### Null-aware operator works like guard let or if let in swift.

[image]

??
Use ?? when you want to evaluate and return an expression IFF another expression resolves to null.

```
exp ?? otherExp
```

is similar to

```
((x) => x == null ? otherExp : x)(exp)
```

??=
Use ??= when you want to assign a value to an object IFF that object is null. Otherwise, return the object.

```
obj ??= value
```

is similar to

```
((x) => x == null ? obj = value : x)(obj)
```

?.
Use ?. when you want to call a method/getter on an object IFF that object is not null (otherwise, return null).

```
obj?.method()
```

is similar to

```
((x) => x == null ? null : x.method())(obj)
```

You can chain ?. calls, for example:

```
obj?.child?.child?.getter
```

If obj, or child1, or child2 are null, the entire expression returns null. Otherwise, getter is called and returned.

Ref: http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html

Also Check Soundness in dart
https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system